# How to clear all radio buttons using right click in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to clear all radio buttons in a group if I right click on one of them.
How can I implement this using Javascript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than

```
Right click an option to deselect:

(*) option 1
( ) option 2
( ) option 3
```

which is abusing the user interface, you're better to do this:

```
( ) none
(*) option 1
( ) option 2
( ) option 3
```

Comment: I don't want to add the "none" option to the interface.
The right click option is only for debugging purposes.

Comment: I don't see the value in using this for debugging, there is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: OK,I'll try to explain.I have a form with lots of radio button groups.
I have a Javascript code that fills the form randomly. After this is done, I would like to be able to clear all buttons of some groups, then submit the form and check that the validation works fine.

Comment: if you have a form with so many radio button groups that you need a script just to fill it in for you, you might have deeper problems. I don't understand why you can't just submit the form without selecting any of the options, or not allow there to be no selections (in a radio button group, there should always be exactly one selection, no more or less) by selecting one of the options by default.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you can't unselect radio buttons. The point of a radio button group is that at least one needs to be selected. It could actually be considered a bug that it's possible to have a radio button group in which no item is selected.

I suppose you'd have to remove and re-generate the group to clear the selection, exploiting this "bug".

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link at quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) on capturing the right mouse click. The combination of an element and a right click should let you uncheck all radio buttons in a given group.

Comment: @Carson Myers and @deceze both have the correct idea. While it is possible to do, a better question is **should** it be done?

Comment: Thank you for the link. There is one problem: when I left click on a radio button I can recognize that (display alert message for example), but when I right click on it, Firefox context menu is opened instead. How can I fix this ?